# D STL Containers Phobos - How do I use a range?

Tags: stl, range, d

I cannot find any good documentation on how to use a range in conjunction with a container. I'm trying to insert an element into a SList using the given .insertAfter() function. It takes a range though and I have no idea how to retrieve it.

Can someone please post an example or two of how to use this poorly documented feature?

This is the D documentation for containers - http://dlang.org/phobos/std_container.html

I've also read ranges can be used like c++ iterators. If this is true how can I use a range in a loop?

Comment: I've created a [pull request for Phobos](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/628) to document how this function is to be used more clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the slice operator (`[]`)to get the range of a container

to iterate over a container you can do:

```
foreach(el;container[]){

}
```

a range has a front property which is the element currently pointed at, the popFront of a range will move the range to the next element and empty will indicate whether the range is at the end

the foreach loop above is equivalent to

```
for(auto range=container[];!range.empty;range.popFront()){
    auto el = range.front;

}
```

to insert into the middle of the list you'll need to do

```
container.insertAfter(take(container[],5),element);
```

to insert at the end it's

```
container.insertAfter(container[],element);
```